# Outside url for post content

Tags: embed

I'm creating a widget to embed from outside of wordpress that will contain the post content. I don't want to use the permalink because that will include the whole page. I'm thinking I can grab the post id, but not sure how to call the url of only the post content from outside of wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a built-in feature, but if you install the [Show Content Only plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/show-content-only/) into WordPress, this functionality will be available - simply add:

```
?content-only=1
```

... to the end of the post URL to get the content only.

Comment: Thanks, Gavin! I'll give it a shot, but I'm also interested if anyone has a solution that doesn't require a plugin.

Comment: This is not a core WordPress feature.

Comment: This won't work for my purposes, because my content (not using it in the strictest wordpress terminology) is a collection of fields passed through custom meta boxes. So I'm not looking for what shows up in the editor, just the title and my custom fields that display at the url via a custom page template.